# How to send location coordinates when uploading a picture?

Tags: javascript, php, html, leaflet, location

The page has a leaflet map on it. Additionally, there is a form for image uploading and a marker displaying user's location on the map. I need the location coordinates to be sent over to a page "savetofile.php" whenever 'Upload' button is clicked.

Currently the picture uploading works, the picture information is sent correctly, and the input from notes is also sent correctly. I need the coordinates to be set from the location and not hardcoded as they are right now.

Form

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" id="form1" method="post">
    <div>
        <label for="fileToUpload">Take or select photo(s)</label><br/>
        <input accept="image/*" capture id="fileToUpload" name="fileToUpload" onchange="fileSelected();"
               type="file"/>
    </div>
    <div>
        <label for="notes">Notes:</label>
        <textarea cols="50" id="notes" maxlength="2000" name="notes" placeholder="Please enter any additional information here"
                  rows="4" onchange="this.form.submit()"></textarea>
        <br><br>
    </div>
    <div id="details"></div>
    <div>
        <input onclick="uploadFile()" type="button" value="Upload"/>
    </div>
    <div id="progress"></div>
</form>
```

uploadFile()

```
function uploadFile() {
            var fd = new FormData();
            var count = document.getElementById('fileToUpload').files.length;

            var latitude = 27.7823;//position.coords.latitude; //Get latitude HARDCODED
            var longitude = -97.5606;//position.coords.longitude; //Get longitude HARDCODED

            for (var index = 0; index < count; index++) {
                var file = document.getElementById('fileToUpload').files[index];
                fd.append('myFile', file);
            }
            // Send input from Notes
            fd.append('notes', document.getElementById('notes').value);
            // Send coordinates
            fd.append('coord_latitude', latitude);
            fd.append('coord_longitude', longitude);

            var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

            xhr.upload.addEventListener("progress", uploadProgress, false);
            xhr.addEventListener("load", uploadComplete, false);
            xhr.addEventListener("error", uploadFailed, false);
            xhr.addEventListener("abort", uploadCanceled, false);
            xhr.open("POST", "/web/uas_tools/visualization_generator/V2/Resources/PHP/savetofile.php");
            xhr.send(fd);
        }
```

savetofile.php

```
$longitude = $_POST['coord_longitude'];
_log('longitude: ' .$longitude);

$latitude = $_POST['coord_latitude'];
_log('latitude: ' .$latitude);
```

How marker is created and updated using location

```
const marker = L.marker([0, 0]).bindPopup("You are here").addTo(map);  //Start marker

function success(position) {
    const latitude = position.coords.latitude; // Get latitude
    const longitude = position.coords.longitude;// Get longitude

    marker.setLatLng([latitude, longitude]).addTo(map);

    status.textContent = '';
}
?>
```

Console output

```
longitude: -97.5606
latitude: 27.7823
Image has been uploaded.
```

Comment: In `uploadFile()` you're using a variable `position`. Where is that initialised?

Comment: Can you specify some details about how it "breaks the code"? What does the console show?

Comment: @TangentiallyPerpendicular it is not initialized. It comes from ```function success(position)```. I just copied the code from there

Comment: @El_Vanja it doesn't load savetofile.php. Console doesn't show errors

Comment: @mark I don't see how the `position` variable passed to `success()` is in scope when you call `uploadFile()`.  There's a number of disparate pieces of code here and it's difficult to see how they fit together. I think you have an undefined variable, but I'd expect to see a message on the browser console.